# Error: undefined symbol: ADtoDBM

Tags: assembly, undefined-symbol

I've been troubleshooting this error for about 6 hours and I CANNOT figure it out.  I have one project that is very similar that works just fine, but I can't get this to assemble correctly.  I get 4 errors that all say "Undefined symbol: ADtoDBM"

```
.macro cpsne
       cp   @0, @1
       in   r0, SREG
       sbrc     r0, 1
.endmacro

.macro  Output
    ldi     r16, @0
    rcall       SerialPutChar
.endmacro 

.macro LONGRCALL
    ldi     ZH, high(@0) ;the error points me to this line
    ldi     ZL, low(@0) ;the error points me to this line
    icall
.endmacro

.macro  SRAMToEE
    lds     r16, @0
    out     EEDR, r16
    sts     @1, r16
    ldi     r16, @1
    out     EEARL, r16
    rcall       EEWrite
.endmacro
```

I labeled the 2 lines that throw the error under macro LONGRCALL.

It also points me to 2 other locations, one of which is posted here and the other one is pretty much the exact same thing.

```
Filter_SS:
    ldi     r17, 'S'
    cpse        r16, r17
     rjmp       Filter_SF

    rcall       QueueInit       
    LONGRCALL   ADtoDBM ;error points to this line.
    clr     r18
    longrcall   HexToBCD
    mov     r16, r12
    mov     r17, r13
    rcall       hex2Ascii
    mov     r16, r21
    rcall       SerialPutChar
    mov     r16, r20
    rcall       SerialPutChar
    mov     r16, r19
    rcall       SerialPutChar
    ldi     r16, '.'
    rcall       SerialPutChar
    mov     r16, r18
    rcall       SerialPutChar

    rjmp        prompt
```

The ADtoDBM points to another source file which is posted below

```
ADtoDBM:

lds r16, InputStatus
sbrs    r16, 0
rjmp    ADtoDBMStart
ldi r16, 0x0f   ; HEX for 9999  
ldi r17, 0x27 
ret
```

I did not write this code.  It was written about 15 years ago for an old product that we made but no longer do.  Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Tucker

Comment: `ADtoDBM points to another source file` ... is it marked as global in that file, so that it's visible during linking? You **do** link to that object file, right?

Comment: I include all the necessary files for it to run.  Like I said I have another one that is similar, (same basic code) and it works fine.  I compared the 2 projects and they both include all of the same files.

Comment: The only problem evident from what you posted is that `ADtoDBM` hasn't been declared as global, though maybe that's not necessary with whatever assembler you're using. If that's not the problem then the problem likely lies with something you haven't mentioned.